Why is my QUIC connection not exchanging data while TCP works fine in Rust?
I am developing a communication layer in Rust that supports both TCP and QUIC protocols for data exchange between a client and a server. The TCP implementation works flawlessly, but the QUIC setup is experiencing issues with data transmission, despite a successful connection.Complete code
Setup and Execution Commands
Use the following commands to test the setup in both TCP and QUIC modes:

TCP Listener: cargo run -- listener tcp
TCP Client: cargo run -- conn tcp
QUIC Listener: cargo run -- listener quic
QUIC Client: cargo run -- conn quic

Observed Behavior
TCP Mode (Working Fine)

TCP Listener: The server starts successfully and properly receives data from the client.
TCP Client: The client connects successfully and exchanges messages with the server.

Example Output:

TCP Listener Output:
Running as tcp listener on 127.0.0.1:5000
Tcp listener started at 127.0.0.1:46220
Received from client: [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 102, 114, 111, 109, 32, 99, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116]


TCP Client Output:
Running as tcp client connecting to 127.0.0.1:5000
Received from server: [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 102, 114, 111, 109, 32, 115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114]



QUIC Mode (Data Transmission Issue)

QUIC Listener: The server starts, listens, and successfully accepts a connection from the client, but it does not receive any meaningful data. Instead, it shows an empty array [].
QUIC Client: The client connects without errors, but no data is exchanged.

Example Output:

QUIC Listener Output:
QUIC server started on 127.0.0.1:5000
Running as quic listener on 127.0.0.1:5000
Connection received from 127.0.0.1:6000
Received from client: []


QUIC Client Output:
Attempting to connect to server at 127.0.0.1:5000
Connected to server



Key Points of Concern

Connection Success without Data Exchange: The QUIC client and listener establish a connection successfully, but no actual data is exchanged.
Empty Data Received: The QUIC listener shows an empty message ([]), suggesting either a transmission or reception issue.
Working TCP Implementation: Since TCP works fine, this indicates that the setup for message handling is likely correct, and the issue may be specific to the QUIC stream handling.

Relevant Code Snippets
Here are some relevant code snippets for the Listener, Conn, and QUIC implementations.
Trait Definitions for Conn and Listener
use async_trait::async_trait;
use std::error::Error;

#[async_trait]
pub trait Conn {
    async fn send(&mut self, data: &[u8]) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>;
    async fn receive(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>;
}

#[async_trait]
pub trait Listener {
    async fn accept(&self) -> Result<Box<dyn Conn + Send + Sync>, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>;
}

QuicListen Implementation
use quinn::{Endpoint, ServerConfig};
use rustls::pki_types::{CertificateDer, PrivatePkcs8KeyDer};
use std::{error::Error, fs, net::SocketAddr, sync::Arc};
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;
use crate::conn::Conn;
use crate::listener::Listener;

pub struct QuicListen {
    pub(crate) endpoint: Endpoint,
}

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl Listener for QuicListen {
    async fn accept(&self) -> Result<Box<dyn Conn + Send + Sync>, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
        let conn = self.endpoint.accept().await;
        let connection = conn.unwrap().await?;
        println!("Connection received from {:?}", connection.remote_address());
        let connection_clone = connection.clone();

        // Accept a unidirectional receive stream
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            if let Ok(mut recv_stream) = connection_clone.accept_uni().await {
                println!("Accepted unidirectional stream"); // Debug statement
                let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
                match recv_stream.read(&mut buffer).await {
                    Ok(Some(n)) => {
                        println!("Received message from client: {:?}", &buffer[..n]);
                    }
                    Ok(None) => println!("Client closed the stream"),
                    Err(e) => eprintln!("Error receiving message: {:?}", e),
                }
            } else {
                eprintln!("Failed to accept unidirectional stream");
            }
        });

        Ok(Box::new(QuicDummyConn {
            connection,
        }))
    }
}

QuicConn Implementation
use std::{error::Error, fs, net::SocketAddr, sync::Arc};
use quinn::{ClientConfig, Connection as QuicConnection, Endpoint, RecvStream, SendStream};
use rustls::pki_types::CertificateDer;
use crate::conn::Conn;
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;

pub struct QuicConn {
    pub(crate) connection: QuicConnection,
    pub(crate) send_stream: SendStream,
}

#[async_trait]
impl Conn for QuicConn {
    async fn send(&mut self, data: &[u8]) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
        println!("Sending from quic connection");
        self.send_stream.write_all(data).await?;
        Ok(())
    }

    async fn receive(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
        let mut buffer = vec![0; 1024];
        match self.recv_stream.read(&mut buffer).await? {
            Some(n) => {
                buffer.truncate(n);
                Ok(buffer)
            }
            None => Err("Stream closed".into()),
        }
    }
}


In summary, TCP functions as expected, while QUIC fails to transmit data. I would appreciate any guidance on resolving the empty data issue with QUIC, particularly around QUIC’s stream handling or possible data flushing requirements. Thank you!

Testing Both TCP and QUIC Modes:

I set up the server to handle connections and data exchange for both TCP and QUIC modes. The TCP mode worked as expected, with the client successfully sending and receiving messages from the server.


Debugging QUIC Connection and Data Exchange:

For the QUIC implementation, I ensured that the client and server established a connection by checking for "Connection received" on the server side. This confirmed that the QUIC connection was established successfully.
I added debug statements to monitor the data sent from the client and received by the server, which showed an empty message ([]), indicating that data was not being transmitted correctly.


Verifying Data Send and Stream Closure:

I made sure to call write_all on the QUIC send stream and tried to close the stream using finish().await? on the client side, to ensure the data was flushed to the server.



What I Expected
I expected the QUIC implementation to behave similarly to the TCP implementation, where:

The client connects to the server.
The client sends a message to the server, and the server receives the full message.

In QUIC mode, the server correctly receives the connection but consistently reads an empty message, even though the client indicates it has sent data. I expected the server to receive the same message content that was successfully sent and received in TCP mode. Complete code

One error exists in your complete code:
transport_config.max_concurrent_uni_streams(0_u8.into());

This will prevent any unidirectional streams from being opened, such as the one the client tries to open:
let send_stream = connection.open_uni().await?;

Admittedly, this theory cannot explain why the code makes it to the read:
Received from client: []

Please raise the limit to 1 and update your question if you are still experiencing a problem.
